# Is fast (repeated) undo possible in emacs?

Tags: emacs, editor, undo

I use emacs and I have a problem with it's undo.

(Sorry, maybe this is a stupid question, but I did not find anything about it in the internet, whilst it should be a basic functionality of any editor).

To invoke each undo step I need to press 'Ctrl-x' and then 'u'.
But if I have done 200 steps and I wish to undo them, my hand and fingers get horrible pain from repeating 'Ctrl-x' and then 'u' 200 times, to say nothing that this operation takes about 5 minutes.

In Microsoft Word, for example (and also in many other editors) undo is Ctlr-Z, but you can press and hold Ctlr-Z and multiple undo steps run fast. Is this achievable in emacs?

Answer (score 22):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, type <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>, then press <kbd>CTRL+x</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd>.

This gives an argument of 200 to the operation you are going to perform next (e.g. undo), so it applies that operation 200 times.

By the way, <kbd>CTRL+/</kbd> is also mapped to "undo", if you would like to use fewer keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks, 'ctrl /' is fine; the matter is not how many kestrokes, the matter is that 'ctrl x u' you cannot hold, but 'ctrl /' you can hold and it runs.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> is essentially the same as the MS Word functionality.

Comment: Actually, ctrl + does not work, but ctrl / does work, many thanks, it really really helped!!!

Comment: The + wasn't part of it... That was just a key combo (could have used AND instead) :P EDIT: choroba, I didn't even know you could do that... Thanks :)

Comment: `C-/` would be the standard way of stating it. Also, unless MS have made radical changes in the past few years, I think it *highly* unlikely that Emacs' undo is similar to Word's undo :)

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found additional way of doing so:
C-x u C-x z z z z z

But ctrl / is easier.

Many thanks to brbcoding

Answer (score 3):

Undo tree is a mode to navigate in the history of recent changes. I think it's better to use this mode for deep undos

Comment: Interesting. It's a package you need to install, e.g. via ELPA: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree